# Microsoft Graph Sign-Ins Audit Logs API : Internal Users are shown as Guest User type for certain logins

Tags: rest, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using MS Graph Sign-in REST API to retrieve the Guest user sign-ins my tenant. But I have retrieved certain sign-ins which are showing the internal users as Guest in User Type attribute.
Also absorbed HomeTenantId and ResourceTenantId also differs.

Certain times, while logging in to Azure AD Portal, directory of the previously logged-in tenant are logged in. In that cases TenantId may differ and userType attribute is shown as Guest. But for SharePoint I am not sure of the user Type guest

This is confusing a bit. Any idea on why Internal users are shown as Guest Users

Request : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns

Sample Response:

```
{   "id": "$$$$$$",
"createdDateTime": "2021-08-29T10:22:06Z",
"userDisplayName": "user",
"userPrincipalName": "user@cortana.onmicrosoft.com",
"userId": "$$$$$",
"appId": "08e18876-6177-487e-b8b5-cf950c1e598c",
"appDisplayName": "SharePoint Online Web Client Extensibility",
"ipAddress": "$$$$$$",
"ipAddressFromResourceProvider": null,
"clientAppUsed": "",
"userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36",
"correlationId": "*********",
"conditionalAccessStatus": "notApplied",
"originalRequestId": "",
"isInteractive": true,
"tokenIssuerName": "",
"tokenIssuerType": "AzureAD",
"processingTimeInMilliseconds": 173,
"riskDetail": "none",
"riskLevelAggregated": "none",
"riskLevelDuringSignIn": "none",
"riskState": "none",
"riskEventTypes": [],
"riskEventTypes_v2": [],
"resourceDisplayName": "Office 365 SharePoint Online",
"resourceId": "$$$$$$$",
"resourceTenantId": "$$$$$$$$$",
"homeTenantId": "#########",
"authenticationMethodsUsed": [],
"authenticationRequirement": "singleFactorAuthentication",
"alternateSignInName": "",  "signInIdentifier": "",
"signInIdentifierType": null,
"servicePrincipalName": null,
"signInEventTypes": ["interactiveUser"],
"servicePrincipalId": "",
"userType": "guest", 
"flaggedForReview": false,
"isTenantRestricted": false,
"autonomousSystemNumber": 45609,
"crossTenantAccessType": "b2bCollaboration",
"servicePrincipalCredentialKeyId": null,
"servicePrincipalCredentialThumbprint": "",
"mfaDetail": null,
"status": {         
    "errorCode": 0,
    "failureReason": "Other.",
    "additionalDetails": null   },
"deviceDetail": {       
    "deviceId": "",
    "displayName": "",
    "operatingSystem": "Windows 10",
    "browser": "Chrome 92.0.4515",
    "isCompliant": false,
    "isManaged": false,
    "trustType": ""
}, "location": {
    "city": "Kallimandayam",
    "state": "Tamil Nadu",
    "countryOrRegion": "IN",
    "geoCoordinates": {
        "altitude": null,
        "latitude": "", 
        "longitude": "" 
    }}, "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies": [],
"authenticationProcessingDetails": [{
        "key": "Login Hint Present",
        "value": "True"         },
    {           
          "key": "User certificate authentication level",
        "value": "singleFactorAuthentication"       }   ],
"networkLocationDetails": [],
"authenticationDetails": [],
"authenticationRequirementPolicies": [],
"sessionLifetimePolicies": [], 
"privateLinkDetails": { 
    "policyId": "",
    "policyName": "",
    "resourceId": "",
    "policyTenantId": "" } }
```

Comment: I am able to reproduce your case. Looking at the docs on [signIn resource type properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signin?view=graph-rest-beta#properties), the field `userType` is not included in the docs. I suggest you focus on the documented fields as Beta APIs are not considered ready.

Answer (score 1):

This is By Design. It is an expected behavior, considering that when a user is accessing a tenant where the user is a guest (inviting tenant), you will have this authentication logged in your side as well. When a user is invited to another directory as a guest, the user will authenticate with the credentials from his home tenant, as explained in the below link.

Reference - Authentication is performed by the guest user's identity provider - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/user-properties

Comment: Agreeing with this answer. Check field `"crossTenantAccessType"`:  (`"b2bCollaboration"` in your case) on the activities